# Android Conversion to Ordinal Format

Tags: android

Before I go reinventing the wheel, does Android have any facility for converting an integer to an ordinal string with multi-language support? That is, it would convert the integer 3 to "3rd" in English and "3eme" in French.

I can see how to do this myself using a bit of logic along with Android's automatic string substitution, but thought that this surely must have been encountered by others, and not just for use with dates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java nor Android have support for creating ordinal strings. Android does have support for creating plural string resources, but not ordinals.

Comment: I was able to solve this issue using the plurals facility, at least well enough for my purposes. It works for English and French in the ranges I'm dealing with, but when I get into further translations I may have to change it again. Mainly, I was trying to come up with a solution where my app would not have to be "aware" of the language being used and could just make use of Android's automatic string support.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is this feature supported now, in Java or Android, or do we still need to write our custom implementation? I haven't been able to find any in-built feature for this yet, but still asking to be sure.

Comment: @KashishMalhotra: I am not aware of this being added to Android, nor in Java at least through Java 8. I would be somewhat surprised if it were added to newer versions of Java, and even if it were, you would not be able to use those with Android app development.

Answer (score 9):

Just for future reference, I came across this issue and discovered that now you can use the ICU MessageFormat to do something like this:

```
import android.icu.text.MessageFormat

fun toOrdinal(day: String): String {
    val formatter = MessageFormat("{0,ordinal}", Locale.getDefault())
    return formatter.format(arrayOf(day.toInt()))
}
```

You will get these results:

```
1 -> 1st
2 -> 2nd
3 -> 3rd
4 -> 4th
5 -> (...)
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this is useful starting from API 24.

Answer (score 7):

If the range for which you need ordinals is limited, then you are probably best to use a `<string-array>` to define them:

```
<string-array name="ordinals">
  <item>zeroth</item>
  <item>1st</item>
  <item>2nd</item>
  <item>3rd</item>
  <item>4th</item>
  <item>5th</item>
  <item>6th</item>
</string-array>
```

and then access it via:

```
String ordinal = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ordinals)[count];
```

Of course this doesn't get you automatic translation into other languages - you have to do that yourself (and if your count goes outside the range in this simplistic code you will get an exception).